# About vector transpose $uu^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, transpose

I have some questions regarding vector Transpose.

Let $u \in \Bbb R^n$, such that $||u||=1$ and let $A=uu^T$.

So I understand that $A$ is a $\Bbb n ~{\Bbb x}~\Bbb n$ matrix.

I want to find $\Bbb {nul}A$.

So for $u=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\\ 
\vdots \\ 
a_n
\end{bmatrix}$ we have $uu^T=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1a_1 &\cdots   & a_1a_n\\ 
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ 
a_na_1 &\cdots   & a_na_n
\end{bmatrix}$

Then $\Bbb {nul}A= \Bbb {nul}\begin{bmatrix}
a_1a_1 &\cdots   & a_1a_n\\ 
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ 
a_na_1 &\cdots   & a_na_n
\end{bmatrix}=\Bbb {nul} \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 &\cdots   & a_n\\ 
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ 
a_1 &\cdots   & a_n
\end{bmatrix}=\Bbb {nul} \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 &\cdots   & a_n\\ 
\vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots  \\ 
0 &\cdots   & 0
\end{bmatrix} ~~ \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow ~~a_1=-a_2-a_3-...-a_n$

$\Rightarrow \Bbb{nul}A =\Bbb{span}\begin{Bmatrix}
-1 & -1 & \cdots & -1\\ 
1 &  0&  \cdots & 0\\ 
0 &  1& \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{Bmatrix}$

Which should be $= \Bbb{span}\left \{ u \right \}^{\perp}$

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to find $\rm nul A = nul$... nul what?

Comment: Geometrically, $uu^T$ is the projection onto the subspace spanned by $u$. From this the fact that $\text{null}(uu^T)$ is $\text{span}(u)$'s orthogonal complement practically falls out.

Comment: One of your steps seems to suggest that the span of a 0/1/-1 matrix that has nothing to do with $u$ is the same as $null(A)$, which does not make sense.  I observe that any vector $x$ orthogonal to $u$ will lead to $u^Tx=0$ and hence $Ax=0$.

Comment: $ \text{nul} A = \{x | A x = 0\} = \{x | u u^T x = 0\} = \{x | u^T x = 0\}$ , thus $\text{nul} A $ is the orthogonal complement of $\text{span}{u}$, i.e. it contains all the vectors that are orthogonal to $u$.  Suppose $ u = [1, 2, 3]^T$ then orthogonal vectors include $[2, -1, 0]^T, [3, 0, -1]^T$ , etc., the dimension of the orthgonal complement is $n-1$.

Comment: We have $uu^Tx = (x, u)u$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the dot product. Thus $uu^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\text{span}(u)$. In particular, $N(uu^T) = \text{span}(u)^{\perp}$.